# Editing a Textfield in a Detail Controller After Clicking a Cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a little trouble editing names in a cell after a user inputted them in. 
Essentially they click on a button 'add name' which takes them to a detail Controller and they enter in their first and last name and click 'done'. That delegates back to the master Controller and the cell is updated to show that name. 

What I'd like is for them to be able to input many names and then click on a cell afterwards which takes them back to the data they've already inputted (which is stored in an NSMutableArray called 'entry').

```
-(void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
     self.detailView.firstNameField.text = [[self.entry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]firstName]];  
     NSLog(@"%@",[[self.entry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]firstName]);
     NSLog(@"%@", self.detailView.firstNameField.text);
}
```

The first NSLog shows the name just fine, but the second comes back as "null" and the textfields are blank, ready to have a new name added...
All and any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How do you create self.detailVIew.firstNameField ?

Comment: In my main view controller.h with @property DetailViewController *detailView

Comment: No, i meant the firstNameField ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing this the wrong way the way it works, you dont set values directly to the `UITextfield` , Instead you pass it a `NSString` which would be a property of your model.

That is the whole point of `MVC` the data should not interact with the `UI` directly.

In your `MasterViewController` you need to import the `DetailViewController` header:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
```

perform the segue in the `didSelectedRow`:

```
-(void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

implement the segue deleguate and set its firstName property (`NSSrting`)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    DetailViewController*detailView = (DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.firstName =[[self.entry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]firstName]]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",[[self.entry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]firstName]);
  }
}
```

then in viewDidLoad of DetailView you would assign the `firstName` string to your `UItextfield` text property:

```
_firstNameField.text = self.firstName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! worked perfectly, you're an angel :)